# how to remain state unchanged while opening popup in ui router?

Tags: angularjs

Project has one popup and I need to open popup from multiple ui-views.But when I do so the url changes and state changes to default view.How can I make the state or view remains unchanged.Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The pop-up is defined as a state?

Comment: NO.I am using bootstrap model

Comment: Can you edit your question and post some more code please? How have you defined your model, from where are you calling it and how are you calling it?